# React Native SectionList has incomprehensible flow type error

Tags: list, react-native, flowtype

If have this simple [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) definition in my code:

```js
const s = (
  <SectionList
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>abc</Text>}
    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => <Text>abc</Text>}
    sections={[{ data: [1, 2, 3], title: 'abc' }]}
  />
);
```

And flow generates this error message which refers to the whole "tag block" (it is actually copy pasted from VSCode):

```
[flow] props of React element `SectionList` (This type is incompatible with See also: React element `SectionList`)
```

What is happening here?

**EDIT** I am using

```
flow-bin: 0.56.0
react: 16.0.0
react-native: 0.49.1
```

**EDIT2** So the example can be reduced to this simple line (without impacting the error message):

```js
<SectionList sections={[]} />;
```

**EDIT3** I just discovered that flow complains about several types that are defined in the React Native library (mainly about missing type arguments for generic types). I am wondering if I should use an older flow-bin version. Is there a compatibility table for React Native and flow?

Comment: Which version of react-native are you using? react-native's code contains Flow annotations, so you can see exactly what it's expecting by looking at the code for SectionList: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/790eabcdff18470571b3f9a5355c924495015918/Libraries/Lists/SectionList.js

Comment: Yeah... well, I still have no clue. However, I added the library version numbers.

Comment: The 0.49-stable branch of react-native uses `^0.53.0` as its flow-bin dependency version. Try reverting to v0.53.0. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.49-stable/package.json

Comment: I tried it, the error message still appears. However, the app works flawlessly. Thus, I will be ignoring this error message henceforth.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with `react-native: 0.49.3` and `flow-bin: 0.53.0`. After checking the type definitions from the `SectionList` source, got it to work without type warnings as follows:

```
type Row = {
  name: string,
}

type Section = {
  title: string,
  data: $ReadOnlyArray<Row>,
}

const mySections: $ReadOnlyArray<Section> = [...] // your data here

<SectionList sections={mySections} />
```

So the key for me was to use `$ReadOnlyArray<T>` instead of `Array<T>`. Perhaps this helps you!

Comment: This does not change anything for me.

Answer (score 4):

React has a built in Flow type for sections called `SectionBase`:

```
import type { SectionBase } from 'react-native/Libraries/Lists/SectionList'
type Section = SectionBase<DataType>
```

So based on what Martin answered you would write: `SectionBase<Row>`

Answer (score 1):

The OP's code should have gotten no complaints from Flow as it is valid.

I had a related issue in that I was using a state that held sections and I could not find the right type for Flow. I could not use SectionBase directly since it did not have the extra `title` property I needed. I solved it by using an intersection type:

```
type Section = { title: string } & SectionBase<ScheduleChange>
type State { sections: Section[] }

...

<SectionList
    sections = this.state.sections
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface SectionDataModel {
...
}
```

`const [sections, setSections] = useState<ReadonlyArray<SectionDataModel> | []>([])`
This worked for me